# Algebraic geometry interpretation of deducing $\Re(z)= -1$ from $(z+2)^6=z^6$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099836/equation-in-the-complex-field#3099846) asks

> [I]f $z$ is a solution of the equation 
>   $$(z+2)^6=z^6$$
>   then we must have $\Re (z)=-1$.

How can I translate the geometry of that question into algebraic geometry, and break it down into a polynomial equation system? (Or, if I am mistaken and this is not possible, why doesn't it work?)

The reason which makes me think this works is that :

1. $Re(z) = k$ for a complex $z$ is a line in the plane. A line in the plane is also a linear equation ( multivariate polynomial of order 1  ). Using convention $z = a+bi$ $$1\cdot a + 0\cdot b  +1=0$$
2. the fact that a complex polynomial we can split into a separate polynomial for real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be formulated as a system of polynomial equations, but this doesn't seem helpful.

First of all expanding $(z+2)^6=z^6$ yields
$$12z^5+60z^4+160z^3+240z^2+192z+64=0,$$
and next writing $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ yields the equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
0&=&12(x^5+5x^4yi-10x^3y^2-10x^2y^3i+5xy^4+y^5i)\\
&+&60(x^4+4x^3yi-6x^2y^2-4xy^3i+y^4)\\
&+&160(x^3+3x^2yi-3xy^2-y^3i)\\
&+&240(x^2+2xyi-y^2)\\
&+&192(x+yi)\\
&+&64.
\end{eqnarray*}
Collecting terms yields the two equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
(12x^5-120x^3y^2+60xy^4)+(60x^4-360x^2y^2+60y^4)+(160x^3-480xy^2)+(240x^2-240y^2)+192x+64=0,\\
(60x^4y-120x^2y^3+12y^5)+(240x^3y-240xy^3)+(480x^2y-160y^3)+480xy+192y=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows the solution set is the intersection of a quintic and a quartic surface. The corresponding geometric picture isn't particularly illuminating, but as noted in the comments, the quartic polynomial is a multiple of $y$. Setting $y=0$ takes us back to our original quintic, but now in the real variable $x$ in stead of the complex variable $z$.

---

What makes the answer work, is the observation that any solution $z\in\Bbb{C}$ must satisfy $|z+2|=|z|$. This is equivalent to solving
$$(z+2)(\overline{z+2})=z\overline{z},$$
and here writing $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ yields the equation
$$x^2+4x+4+y^2=x^2+y^2,$$
from which it easily follows that $x=-1$. From here it is not hard to find the appropriate values of $y$.

Comment: Nice work deriving equations. It is clear we can factor out $y$ from the second equation. But other than that I agree maybe they are not so easy to rewrite... But I also do not know so many algebraic geometric algorithms, so maybe it is possible, but I just don't know how? (Also I suspect we can factor out $(x+1)$ at some stage.). The way I am used to approach this would be by "blind deconvolution" techniques, but I suspect some algebraic geometric ones can be more efficient...

Comment: Indeed $y$ is a factor of the quartic, and the corresponding slice of the quintic surface is precisely our original quintic polynomial.